# Why my android app does not work, when I build it as android app bundle?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I want to start publish my app as AAB. I successfully build my **build.aab** file and decide to try install app on my phone.
I use next way

1) Build APK set from aab file with command:

```
java -jar bundletool.jar  build-apks 
--bundle=*path to aab* 
--output=*path to apks*
--connected-device 
--ks=*android debug keystore path*
--ks-key-alias=androiddebugkey 
--adb=*path to adb*
```

2) Install with next command:

```
java -jar bundletool.jar install-apks 
--apks=*path to apks*
--adb=*path to adb*
```

App is successfully installed, but when I launch it I see only white screen. It reproduces on all devices.

When I use `--universal` instead of `--connected-device` all works good.

I also try to publish test version of my app. It is successfully downloaded and installed, but crash on the start without any errors. In LogCat I detect next suspicious logs:

```
[12-09 16:56:26.324 754:754 E/ANDR-IOP]
IOP HAL: Received pkg_name = com.sampleApp.android.vsm.dji pid = -1

[12-09 16:56:26.895 8110:8110 I/zygote64]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar", zip file 
"/data/app/com.sampleApp.android.vsm.dji-ToIZw7tZAA9jyANJ4k4SQA==/base.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.sampleApp.android.vsm.dji-ToIZw7tZAA9jyANJ4k4SQA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.sampleApp.android.vsm.dji-ToIZw7tZAA9jyANJ4k4SQA==/split_config.ru.apk", zip file 
"/data/app/com.sampleApp.android.vsm.dji-ToIZw7tZAA9jyANJ4k4SQA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk", dex file "InMemoryDexFile[cookie=[0, 
491834627968]]", dex file "InMemoryDexFile[cookie=[0, 
491834628128]]"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sampleApp.android.vsm.dji-ToIZw7tZAA9jyANJ4k4SQA==/lib/arm64, 
/data/app/com.sampleApp.android.vsm.dji-ToIZw7tZAA9jyANJ4k4SQA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, 
/data/app/com.sampleApp.android.vsm.dji-ToIZw7tZAA9jyANJ4k4SQA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, 
/data/app/com.sampleApp.android.vsm.dji-ToIZw7tZAA9jyANJ4k4SQA==/sp
```

Comment: What are the files in the `.apks` file? You should have a `toc.pb`, one `base-master.apk` and at least one other (you can rename .apks to .zip and use any zip editor to look into it).

Comment: Yeah, there is a `toc.pb` file and `base-master.apk` into *.apks file. Also *.apks contains `base-xxhdpi.apk`, `base-ru.apk` and `base-arm64_v8a.apk`. All apk files are in the "splits" folder.

Comment: That looks good. If you install these APKs manually running `adb install-multiple base-master.apk base-xxhdpi.apk base-ru.apk base-arm64_v8a.apk`, does your app work? If so, might be an issue with bundletool. If not, this might be an issue with the device. What device are you installing it on?

Comment: `adb install-multiple` give the same result. I tried to install app to several devices, so I think this is not device-specific problem. I update question with LogCat logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turn out some of libraries, that I use, don't support AAB build.

Make sure that all dependencies that you use support AAB build so as not to repeat my mistakes and to save ton of time.

Comment: Interesting. May I ask how you were able to determine which libraries don't support AAB build?

Comment: @Nikolay can you share some details?

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that react native 0.61.5 causes a similar problem in my project. (different error, but the app basically hangs upon start. It happens only when distributed as AAB, and only if react native is included in the build)

Comment: Seconded - did you figure out how to know if libraries support AAB? There is a deadline soon for Google mandating AAB and I'm stuck!

Comment: @Nikolay - enquiring minds want to know!   :)   How were you able to determine which libraries don't support AAB?

Comment: Oh, it was so long time ago. I don't clearly remember, but I was tring next:
1) See documentation. Sometimes libraries developers specify if their products doesn't support aab.
2) See errors in the logcat. In my case it was a DJI lib for a drone control. You can see it in my error log