# How to determine whether an Android library supports AAB builds?

Tags: android, apk

My Android app works fine as an APK package, but when archiving to an AAB package, the app just freezes on startup. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59351470/909180) suggests that not all libraries support AAB builds. I do use some third-party libraries.

How can I determine whether a library supports AAB builds?

Comment: Which third-party libraries do you use?

Comment: `Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes`, `Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics` and `sqlite-net-sqlcipher`. Besides from those also a couple of `Xamarin.*`.

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this? I have an app that uses third party libraries and Google Play are mandating AAB's very soon, but I can't get past the AAB crashing on start :(

Comment: Nope, I did not.